# Drivers of Fiona

Tags: python, fiona

What drivers does the python package `fiona` have?
When I check the [manual](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html#writing-new-files) it says `[...] and the possible formats are enumerated in the fiona.drivers list.`
However, when I type in python

```
from fiona import drivers
print drivers
> <function drivers at 0x108763050>
```

How can I look "into" that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you can get a list of the drivers with

```
>>> import fiona
>>> fiona.supported_drivers
{'ESRI Shapefile': 'raw', 'ARCGEN': 'r', 'PCIDSK': 'r', 'SUA': 'r', 
'DGN': 'raw', 'SEGY': 'r', 'MapInfo File': 'raw', 'GeoJSON': 'rw', 'PDS': 'r', 
'FileGDB': 'raw', 'GPX': 'raw', 'DXF': 'raw', 'GMT': 'raw', 'Idrisi': 'r', 
'GPKG': 'rw', 'OpenFileGDB': 'r', 'BNA': 'raw', 'AeronavFAA': 'r', 
'GPSTrackMaker': 'raw'}
```

<strike>The function is being introduced in the module's [**init**.py](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/blob/master/fiona/__init__.py#L73) file</strike>

please also see [drvsupport.py](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/blob/master/fiona/drvsupport.py) for some notes from the authors that you may or may not find useful.

Comment: Do any of these drivers work for reading a spatialite file?

Comment: Unfortunately no as far as I can tell. You might want to check geoalchemy2