# Exporting multiple GeoPandas GeoDataFrames to one KMZ file

Tags: export, geopandas, kmz, geodataframe

I have two GeoPandas GeoDataFrames, and I want to export them to a KMZ file with a nested folder structure. Below is a stand-alone code to create the GeoDataFrames, and a screenshot of how I would like the KMZ structure to look.

I want to do this without ArcGIS or QGIS. Using Python 3.7.

```py
###############################################
### load libraries
###############################################
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry import LineString

###############################################
### Build Stand-Alone Geodataframes
### 'p' is a points-type gdf
### 'pl' is a polyline-type gdf
###############################################

pname = ['Project1'] * 5
id1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
lat = [36.42, 36.4, 36.32, 36.28, 36.08]
long = [-118.11, -118.12, -118.07, -117.95, -117.95]
cat = ['X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y']
id2 = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B']
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(pname, id1, lat, long, cat, id2)), 
                  columns =['pname', 'id1', 'lat', 'long', 'cat', 'id2']) 
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)


p = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df['long'], df['lat']))
p = p.set_crs(epsg=4326)
display(p.style)


pl = p.groupby(['pname', 'id2'])['geometry'].apply(lambda x: LineString(x.tolist()))
pl = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pl, geometry='geometry').reset_index()
pl = pl.set_crs(epsg=4326)
display(pl.style)


fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
p.plot(ax=ax1)
pl.plot(ax=ax2)
ax1.set_aspect('equal')
```

[image]

**The desired KMZ structure**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Geopandas is using fiona to handle spatial information, and Fiona doesn't support KMZ I/O.
Reference: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/191380/

```
>>> import fiona
>>> fiona.supported_drivers
{'ESRI Shapefile': 'raw', 'ARCGEN': 'r', 'PCIDSK': 'r', 'SUA': 'r', 
'DGN': 'raw', 'SEGY': 'r', 'MapInfo File': 'raw', 'GeoJSON': 'rw', 'PDS': 'r', 
'FileGDB': 'raw', 'GPX': 'raw', 'DXF': 'raw', 'GMT': 'raw', 'Idrisi': 'r', 
'GPKG': 'rw', 'OpenFileGDB': 'r', 'BNA': 'raw', 'AeronavFAA': 'r', 
'GPSTrackMaker': 'raw'}
```

Therefore, you have to export as KML and pack them with `zipfile`.